# navigation with anchors inside div elements

Tags: ios, html, css, uiwebview

I am showing a html page that is dynamically generated in code. I am inserting navigation points like

```
<div class="columnbreak"><a name="section01"/></div>.
```

I then show this html in a UIWebView. I have a CSS rule for column break

```
div.columnbreak { -webkit-column-break-after : always; }
```

when I try to navigate using javascript

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.location.hash='#%@';", section];
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

it doesn't navigate to the anchor.

if I put the tags in html

```
<div class="columnbreak" ></div><a name="section01"/>
```

then I can navigate with javascript but the column **does not break** properly.

Can anyone give me a hint what is going on ?

Comment: You shouldn't collapse the div tag, as it's not valid HTML. This is better: `<div class="columnbreak"></div>` - it might not be the cause of your problem, but it will give you issues in some browsers.

Comment: I tried it with <div class="columnbreak"></div> as well. If I insert the <a> tag in side the <div> tag the navigation doesn't work... if I put the <a> outside the <div> tag then navigation works but columnbreak doesn't :(

Comment: edited the code to reflect </div> tag

Comment: have you tried not collapsing the a tag as well?

Comment: yes I tested it both ways...                                     I tried to wrap the <a> inside a new <div> as well...then navigation doesn't work. Tried many things... either the column break doesn't work or the navigation :(